# Unable to receive JSON from JQuery ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I have determined that my JSON, coming from the server, is valid (making the ajax call manually), but I would really like to use JQuery. I have also determined that the "post" URL, being sent to the server, is correct, using firebug. However, the error callback is still being triggered (parse error). I also tried datatype: text.

Are there other options that I should include?

```
$(function() {
    $("#submit").bind("click", function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "http://myServer/cgi-bin/broker" ,
            datatype: "json",
            data: {'start' : start,'end' : end},
            error: function(request,error){
                alert(error);
            },
            success: function(request) {
                alert(request.length);
            }
        }); // End ajax
    }); // End bind
}); // End eventlistener
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here are a few suggestions I would try:

1) the 'datatype' option you have specified should be 'dataType' (case-sensitive I believe)

2) try using the 'contentType' option as so:

```
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
```

I'm not sure how much that will help as it's used in the request to your post url, not in the response.
See this article for more info: http://encosia.com/2008/06/05/3-mistakes-to-avoid-when-using-jquery-with-aspnet-ajax
(It's written for asp.net, but may be applicable)

3) Triple check the output of your post url and run the output through a JSON validator just to be absolutely sure it's valid and can be parsed into a JSON object. http://www.jsonlint.com

Hope some of this helps!

Comment: thanks so much for taking the time to answer. it was the dataType option that I had as datatype

Comment: Just a note, setting dataType to "json" automatically sets the contentType to "application/json".

Comment: @BHR +1 correct according to the docs. However, maybe useful to note: I'm working with jquery 1.6.4 atm and have found I need to explicitly set contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"

Answer (score 1):

Why `myResult` instead of `request`?

```
success: function(request) {
  alert(myResult.length);
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure in my full code I was manipulating request into myResult....but I changed it so that it is more clear...the problem was that dataType was spelled as 'datatype'. Thanks for the comment

Answer (score 0):

The data parameter is wrong. Here is an example that works:

data: { index: ddl.selectedIndex },

This contructs an object with property called index with value ddl.selectedIndex.

You need to remove the quotes from your data parameter line

Good luck
A

Comment: -1, it is perfectly valid syntax to have a string as a property name. In some situations it is a must, for example when you have a property name which would not be a valid identifier name in javascript, quoting it will allow you to give it a value anyway. One common example is `"class"`, which has to be quoted as it is a reserved word. In JSON syntax it is even a requirement to wrap all property names in double quotes.